# How to show $[\omega]=0$ implies $[\omega^n]=0$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following: If $(M, \omega)$ is a symplectic manifold and $[\omega]=0$ then $[\omega^n]=0$, where $[\omega]$ is the De Rham cohomology class of $\omega$. Well what I've done was:

Since $\omega$ is exact $\omega=d\tau$ for some $1$-form. Since $\omega^n=d\tau\wedge \omega^{n-1}$ then $$d(\tau\wedge \omega^{n-1})=d\tau \wedge \omega^{n-1}+(-1)^n \tau \wedge d\omega^{n-1}=\omega^n+(-1)^n \tau \wedge d\omega^{n-1},$$ hence $\omega^n=(-1)^{n+1}\tau\wedge d\omega^{n-1}+d(\tau\wedge \omega^{n-1})$. So, for finishing the proof if suffices showing $(-1)^{n+1}\tau\wedge d\omega^{n-1}=0$ but I can't see how to do it.. Can anyone help me? Thanks..

Comment: If $\omega = d\tau$, then $d\omega = 0$.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer, I can't just believe that I didn't see it...

Comment: However, notice that $\omega$ is *closed*, not *exact* by definition, so all this works only locally!

Comment: By definition of the equivalence relation which defines the cohomology class if $\omega\sim \omega^{'}$ then $\omega=\omega^{'}+d\tau$ for some $\tau$. If $[\omega]=0$ then $\omega\sim 0$ hence $\omega=d\tau$. In other words if the cohomology class is zero then the form is exact..

Answer (score 2):

The statement holds for all $n$ and all exact forms $\eta$, so let's use induction.

Since $[\eta] = 0$, we have that $\eta$ is exact and hence $\eta = d\tau$ for some $\tau$.

To see that $[\eta \wedge \eta] = 0$, note that
$$\eta \wedge \eta = d\tau \wedge d\tau =  d(\tau \wedge d\tau).$$

Now suppose that $[\eta^{n-1}] = 0$. Then $\eta^{n-1} = d\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, and we have that
\begin{align*}
\eta^n & = \eta \wedge \eta^{n-1} \\
 & = \eta \wedge d\alpha \\
 & = (-1)^{\deg(\eta)}d(\eta \wedge \alpha),
\end{align*}
where the last equality is true since $d\eta = 0$ by assumption.

Hence by induction if $[\eta] = 0$ for some differential form $\eta$, $[\eta^n] = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: In fact, something stronger holds. If $\eta$ is any closed form, then $[\eta^k]=0\implies [\eta^{k+1}]=0$, since if $\eta^k=\rm d \alpha$, then $\eta^{k+1}=\rm d\alpha\wedge \eta=\rm d(\alpha\wedge \eta)$: The second term vanishes because $\rm d\eta=0$ by assumption.